# Android build fails (aapt2) when building as application as Windows SYSTEM account

Tags: java, android, gradle, teamcity

I have an android build in gradle. ANdroid gradle plugin 3.4.0, android build tools 28.0.3, compile SDK 24, open JDK 8 (ojdkbuild), gradle (wrapper) version 5.4.0. I am able to build and run my application fine on my dev machine, as well as on my TeamCity build agent machine, when running in a cmd prompt as my local user account. However, when TeamCity runs (SYSTEM account), or via a cmd.exe prompt opened as SYSTEM account, I fail with the below error.

I am guessing it's some kind of permission issue of some kind, but unfortunately, I'm not sure how to do a build. Android SDK is installed at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk`. Windows 7 VM.

I've tried downgrading the android gradle plugin, and various searches, but no luck yet.

```
Execution failed for task ':MySubproj:verifyReleaseResources'. com.android.ide.common.workers.WorkerExecutorException: 27 exceptions were raised by workers:
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
```

Comment: Run build under some user that has rights

Comment: rights to what, exactly?

Comment: for example: while building the gradle is creating ".gradle" directory in the current user home directory. Now go into "users" directory and try to search the home directory for the "SYSTEM" user.... So, the simplest way - create a user and start service under this user. Provide access to the building folder. Normally that should be enough to start gradle.

Comment: Creating a separate user was all I had to do. It already had access to `C:\buildagent\work` apparently. Can you write this as an answer so I can give you credit? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while building the `gradle` is creating `.gradle` directory in the current user home directory.

Now go into "users" directory and try to search the home directory for the "SYSTEM" user.... (there is no one)

So, the simplest way - create a user and start service under this user.

Provide access to the building folder. Normally that should be enough to start gradle.

Comment: FYI, the build tools were looking for files in this path, which DID exist, but I think the system account didn't have access to: `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b78af12b786506897709a1ec5e9e70d0\...`

Your suggestion of running TC as a new user account and starting TC as that user rather than SYSTEM did the trick.